# How to color a ggplot according to color stored in a column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have a column containing names of colors, and for each datapoint to be colored according to this.

```
traffic <- structure(list(Sequence = 1:7, Day = c("2013.03.29", "2013.03.28", "2013.03.27", "2013.03.26", "2013.03.25", "2013.03.24", "2013.03.21"), Performance = c("red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "red")), .Names = c("Sequence", "Day", "Performance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

ggplot(traffic, aes(x=Day)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill=Performance)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","yellow", "green"))
```

However, in this case, the colors are switched depending on which values are available in the file (sometimes all three, sometimes only one or two). I tried

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red"="red","yellow"="yellow", "green"="green"))
```

but that didn't draw anything.

Comment: Use scale_fill_identity() instead of scale_fill_manual().

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, thanks so much! If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Can't believe it was so easy, I knew there had to be a way, but couldn't find it no matter where I searched.